# Radix Sort vs Bitonic Sort for floats in cuda

Tags: c++, c, cuda, thrust

I am trying to implement a bitonic sort as part of a closest pair d&c algorithm in cuda and I came across Thrust library. I noticed that it implements radix sort which, from what I have read, is the fastest for integers but is this the same for floats? Would it be better to implement a bitonic sort only for floats or just use the thrust version?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Under GPUs, integer and float instructions have roughly the same latency and throughput. If Thrust is the fastest for integer(`int`), you can assume that it is also the fastest for float too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not write your own sorting algorithm if you're interested in speed.  Sorting is an operation that has received considerable attention, and you're not likely to be able to come up with something as fast as what has been written already, regardless of whether you are using `int` or `float`.

You should consider using an algorithm from [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide), [back40computing](http://code.google.com/p/back40computing/), [moderngpu](http://nvlabs.github.io/moderngpu/), or [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/) for sorting on the GPU.

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying. I totally agree on that point but sometimes you need to sort an array in different patterns. For example I need to have a large array of elements (lets say 100) and I have divided the array in 10 parts each of which i want it to be sorted. I will probabaly open a new question about this but, can this be done with the given implementations of, lets say, Thrust? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: 100 elements is not a large array.  I'm not sure I'm understanding your question.  You can sort an array of any size with thrust.  In fact, with thrust you can do a [vectorized sort](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thrust-users/BoLsxO6b4FY) to sort a number of arrays simultaneously with two operations.

Comment: I mean, I want to sort an array partially, lets say that the 100 elements are in random order. I want to have the array sorted but not as of 100 elements but lets say per 10 elements sorted, leading to smaller sorted fractions of the array. For example from an `A[100`], i want to sort `from A[0] to A[9]`, `A[10] to A[19]` and so on.

Comment: Yes, the vectorized sort link I gave with thrust would do just that.  You could also call it a batch sort.